# Validate data before uploading through SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2005, excel, ssis, upload

I have a SSIS package to upload data from Excel file into an Sql Server 2005 table.

The excel file will have varied lines of data ranging from 20k - 30k lines.

The upload works fine, when all the data are correct.  But obviously fails when there is a small problem even in a single row. Examples like mandatory values presented null, inconvertable values (data type mismatch) etc.

I want to validate the excel file before the upload and want to tell the user which row and column has got the error...

Any idea as to how to accomplish this, without consuming much time and resources.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easiest to load into a temporary table that does not have any mandatory values etc and check that before appending it to the main table.

EDIT re comment

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset 

''This is not necessarily the best way to get the workbook name
''that you need
strFile = Workbooks(1).FullName

''Note that if HDR=No, F1,F2 etc are used for column names,
''if HDR=Yes, the names in the first row of the range
''can be used. 
''This is the Jet 4 connection string, you can get more
''here : http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

 strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

''Note that HDR=Yes
''Pick one:
strSQL = "SELECT Frst, Secnd FROM TheRange WHERE SomeField Is Null" ''Named range
strSQL = "SELECT Frst, Secnd FROM [Sheet1$C3:C67] WHERE Val(Secnd)=0" ''Range
strSQL = "SELECT Frst, Secnd FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE First<Date()" ''Sheet

rs.Open strSQL, cn

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

Comment: Infact I'm doing exactly the same.  But the datatype conversion problem and range conversion problem occurs during the upload to temporary table itself.

Comment: Have you tried writing out to CSV and then importing? If you want the user to make corrections, how about ADO?

Comment: If there is charecter value in numeric field.. Will writing out to CSV will solve the problem.. Or am I missing something.

Comment: I dont know how to work with ADO... Could you please provide some reference material

Comment: If there is character value in numeric field, it should not be a problem for a temporary table that does not require numeric or date or any specific data type in any field. I will post some notes on ADO.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently been working on a number of similar packages in SSIS and the only way that I have been able to get around this is to have a holding table similar [Remou's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912162/validate-data-before-uploading-through-ssis/2912604#2912604) suggestion.

This table is *extremely* generic, where all fields are `NULL`able and `VARCHAR(255)`. I then have a validation Stored Procedure that checks things such as typing, the existance of data etc before I move the data into a "live" situation. Although it may not be the most elegant of solutions, it gives you alot of control of the way you check the data and also means that you shouldn't have to worry about converting the file(s) to .CSV first.

Comment: Okay.. It never occured to me that all the fields are to set up as varchar(255)...